# Pressing button through fragment

Tags: android, button, android-fragments

I'm trying to create an application with fragment on the side as a menu bar.

My main problem is that when I open the fragment I can see the buttons behind it and even press them.

Of course I don't want that. I tried adding the property android:clickable="true" to the layout but it didn't help.

This is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ibuy.ibuy.AddUpdateItem">

    .
    .
    .
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/search_image"
        android:id="@+id/btnBrows"
        android:onClick="openItemTable"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    .
    .
    .

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="ibuy.ibuy.AddUpdateItem"
        android:clickable="true">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:name="Menus.smallMenu"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            android:alpha="255" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code of the listView of the fragment on other file:

```
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#cccc"
    tools:context="Menus.smallMenu"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could use this example  https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you meant by "I can see the buttons behind it". I assume you meant behind the **DrawerLayout** UI.

1)
In that case, you can use the attribute like `android:layout_below="@id/btnBrows"`. As far as I know, all the UI elements should be positioned, otherwise they may be displayed one on top of another, like what you are seeing.

2) Also an issue is that both `android:layout_width` and `layout_height` of `DrawerLayout` is match_parent which fills up the whole screen. It competes screen space with the button. If the button is inside `DrawerLayout`, that would not be an issue but this might be your intentional design.

Answer (score 0):

If you're into Android Studio, create a new **Navigation Drawer Activity**. Take a look at the main XML layout.

The `DrawerLayout` should be your root view. Inside it, you have the `RelativeLayout` with the buttons **and** the `Fragment` that is your navigation drawer.

That way, both are separated and the navigation drawer overlaps correctly when opened.